# Tomcat 8.0.15 Oracle 11 Database and jdbc javax.naming.NamingException

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat, jdbc, junit4

I have an application that i use for buiding reports, now I need to move this application to Web environment.

For that I am using Tomcat 8.0.15 and an Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition.

In my TOMCAT_HOME\conf\server.xml i have the following code:

```
<Resource auth="Container" 
    driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" 
    maxIdle="10" 
    maxTotal="20" 
    maxWaitMillis="-1" 
    name="jdbc/reportDataSource" 
    username="some_username"
    password="some_pass" 
    type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
    url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = some.host)(PORT = some.port)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SID = SOME_SID)(SERVICE_NAME = SOME_SERVICE)))"/>
```

Therefore in my PROJECT_HOME\WebContent\WEB-INF\web.xml I have the following:

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>Oracle Datasource definition</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/reportDataSource</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

Finally in my code I have a Java class with the following:

```
private void init() throws NamingException, SQLException {

    try {

        InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext(); // JNDI initial context
        Context eventContext = (Context) initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/reportDataSource"); // Event context
        dataSource = (DataSource) eventContext.lookup("jdbc/reportDataSource"); // JNDI lookup          
        databaseConnection = dataSource.getConnection(); // database connection through data source

    } catch (SQLException se) {
        throw new SQLException("Connection object was not created. Rejected by host or not found.");
    } catch (NamingException ne) {
        throw new NamingException(ne.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Finally in my project root I have have the following test setup:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {

    dbConnectorManager = new DatabaseConnectorManager();
    assertNotNull(dbConnectorManager);
}
```

When I call the DatabaseConnectorManager() it calls the init() method shown in this question. However when I execute my test I got the following error related with line:

```
entContext eventContext = (Context) initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/reportDataSource"); // Event context
```

Hence, it is not possible to setup JNDI due the following error:

```
javax.naming.NamingException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
```

Can you please advise if I can create these JUnit tests for testing the connectivity, or if I can only test through a servlet?

Is there anything wrong with my configuration?

**Update**

I made the desiganted changes but now I get the following error:

```
javax.naming.NamingException: Name [jdbc/reportDataSource] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [jdbc].
```

My data source now looks like the following:

```
InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext(); // JNDI initial context
        Context eventContext = (Context) initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env"); // Event context
        dataSource = (DataSource) eventContext.lookup("jdbc/reportDataSource"); // JNDI lookup          
        databaseConnection = dataSource.getConnection(); // database connection through data source
```

Comment: Not sure this helps, but take a look at that question maybe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/744389/tomcat-what-is-the-init-context-params-to-use-for-making-an-external-client-con

Answer (score 0):

'not sure this is *the* error, but you probably have a typo here:

```
Context eventContext =
    (Context) initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/reportDataSource"); // Event context
//                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
dataSource = (DataSource) eventContext.lookup("jdbc/reportDataSource"); // JNDI lookup          
//                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

Either you want to do a direct lookup:

```
dataSource =
  (DataSource) initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/reportDataSource");
```

Or you want to get the context first, but in that case, you only requests `java:comp/env`:

```
Context eventContext =
    (Context) initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env");
dataSource = (DataSource) eventContext.lookup("jdbc/reportDataSource");
```

Comment: Hello Sylvain Leroux,

Thank you for your reply. I changed the code as you sugested for:

InitialContext initialContext = new InitialContext(); // JNDI initial context
Context eventContext = (Context) initialContext.lookup("java:comp/env"); // Event context
dataSource = (DataSource) eventContext.lookup("jdbc/reportDataSource"); // JNDI lookup

However, I still have the same error.
My question is, can I look for these resources in a JUnit test, or I can only test this through a servlet?

Best regards,
Ziza

Answer (score 0):

In Server.xml, provide a name to your resource and do the lookup based on that name. Another point is, you can add a resource as a new context.xml under META-INF folder under webapps.  This is done if you don't want to change your server.xml

```
<Resource name="tomcat/JDBCdatasource" auth="Container"  ... />

Context ctx;
ctx = new InitialContext();
Context envContext = (Context) ctx.lookup("java:/comp/env");   
// Look up a data source
javax.sql.DataSource ds
      = (javax.sql.DataSource) envContext.lookup ("tomcat/JDBCdatasource");
```