# Accessing tomcat JNDI tree remotely issue

Tags: java, tomcat, websphere, rmi, tomcat8

While trying to port our application from WAS 8.5.5 to tomcat 8.0.33, we have hit a roadblock and we are unable to proceed. Hence requesting for your inputs.

Following is the scenario: we have  DataSourceManager class which looks for datasource in the context as shown below.

```java
Properties prop = new Properties();

prop.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory");
prop.put("java.naming.provider.url", “rmi://localhost:1099”);

InitialContext context = new InitialContext(prop);
dataSource = (DataSource) context.lookup(“apl_datasource”);
```

The preceding code perfectly works well when code is run within the Tomcat  container. But we are unable to access the context remotely, i.e. from outside the Tomcat container.

But this works fine in case of WAS when `com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory` class is used.

While running a standalone client from a shell script, when inside DataSourceManager class we do a context lookup for a data source and the lookup fails with following exception.

> javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name
>   [java:comp/env/jdbc/apl_datasource] is not bound in this Context.
>   Unable to find [java:comp].

It seems tomcat does not support remote access to its JNDI tree, and context initialized is empty. Tomcat does have the data source in the context but it is only accessible to the process running inside the containers and not accessible to processes running outside the container. PFB the following link for your reference.

[Tomcat: what is the init context params to use for making an external client connection to Tomcat 5.5 JNDI tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/744389/tomcat-what-is-the-init-context-params-to-use-for-making-an-external-client-con)

Kindly provide your inputs on 3 points:

1. This link is for tomcat 5.5 and we are porting to tomcat 8. Has    scenario changed in tomcat8
2. Is there any other way to access the JNDI tree remotely by standalone application.
3. Is the rmi protocol mentioned in provider url is supported by tomcat, or we should change it to some another protocol.

Comment: You are targeting the wrong platform. TomcatEE may support this. AFAIK Tomcat doesn't.

Comment: Thanks @EJP. I understand that we need an application server for this, but isn't there any work around to get the context object remotely.

Comment: The 'workaround' is to use an application server.

Comment: I don't understand why we need an application server to do this, as it's possible to declare jndi resources in tomcat. Does it mean that Tomcat doesn't provide a full implementation of JNDI API ? Is it only an in-memory implementation ?